# Filamentphp Using drag and drop sorting on a custom page

Tags: alpine.js, filamentphp

I want to sort list Using drag and drop sorting on Filamentphp custom page

I used this example

````
<div
    x-data="{}"
    x-sortable
    x-on:end="console.log('Sorting ended!', $event.detail)"
    class="flex flex-col gap-2"
>
    @foreach ($tasks as $task)
        <div
            x-sortable-handle
            x-sortable-item="{{ $task->id }}"
            class="py-2 bg-white px-4"
        >
            {{ $task->title }}
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>```
to sort list, sorting work fine but I have an issue $event.detail is always null, How I can get the sorted list


I try to use `x-on:sortupdate` event but it not works
````

```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `$event.detail`, just use `$event` and you will get all details you want.